# SQL Server 2008 R2: Update with condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table**: `Dots`

```
CREATE TABLE dots
(
    cola VARCHAR(50),
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('59.96.12.563','');
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('594.966.127.5683','');
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('5998.8896.4412.22563','');
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('791','');
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('891','');
INSERT INTO dots VALUES('691','');
```

**Note**: Now I want to update the `NAME` column in the table `Dots` to the value `IP` for those records who contains the 3 dots on it in column `Cola`. For example as shown below in the expected result.

**Result**:

```
Cola                    NAME
--------------------------------                    
59.96.12.563            IP
594.966.127.5683        IP
5998.8896.4412.22563    IP
791
891
691
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code snippet -

```
UPDATE dots SET Name = 'IP' 
WHERE (LEN(cola) - LEN(REPLACE(cola, '.', ''))) / LEN('.')  = 3
```

Comment: this is not a safe way of counting dots in a text. It will fail if the text ends with a space and a dot. Dividing by LEN('.') which equals 1 also seems unnecessary.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - as per me the divide will be required because each time we find the occurrence of '.' we will remove 1 character likewise when we remove 2 characters, we have found '.' twice. 
Also I guess the `LEN(REPLACE(cola, '.', '.X') - LEN(cola)) = 3` will give an error - `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int`

Comment: reason it failed was a misplaced bracked - corrected. My solution will handle  the issue with replacing more letters. Try counting occurrences of space with your syntax. Division by zero. That is what I am trying to explain. Your syntax can't be trusted

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dots
  SET   NAME = 'IP'
  WHERE cola LIKE '%.%.%.%'
```

Comment: No it doesn't validate the `cola` is a valid IP address. Note the requirement is "I want to update the NAME column in the table Dots to the value IP for those records who **contains the 3 dots** on it in column Cola".

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ad99/1 **3 dots means exactly 3 dots, no more no less**

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of checking would be using *LIKE*, this will check for exactly 3 dots:

```
WHERE
  cola like '%.%.%.%'
  and cola not like '%.%.%.%.%'
```

If you fancy the *REPLACE* method. This is the correct syntax:

```
 WHERE 
   LEN(REPLACE(cola, '.', '.X')) - LEN(cola) = 3
```

The reason is that

```
LEN(cola) - LEN(REPLACE(cola, '.', '')) = 3
```

Will fail in case the text ends with space period.

Example:

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE('.  .', '.', ''))
```

Returns 0 indication there are 4 dots in the text.

This may not be an issue since the spaces are probably not existing in your IP addresses.